# How to assign database value to text box in javascript?

Tags: asp.net

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtIssue" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="400px" Height="60px" Text = '<% =GetLabelCaption("Product") %>'>  </asp:TextBox>
```

How to assign database value to a text box in javascript??
GetLabelCaption("Product") is the function returning database value and I want to assign it to the text box.But with my above code value is not getting assigned.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it on server side, may be on Page_Load. The way you are trying is not javascript.

```
txtIssue.Text = GetLabelCaption("Product");
```